# Using different PCL version from ros distribution

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to use PCL 1.6, since it has some bug fixes I need.  I've pieced together that this is possible by downloading the unstable version of the ROS perception_pcl stack and installing the 1.6 PCL binary packages directly.

See the note here regarding using the unstable ROS stack: http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/

However, it's not working because of this renaming scheme they used for the unstable release. It seems that the pcl16_ros package is trying to grab headers from the pcl16 package. But the pcl16 package I checked out has no headers at all and only provides compiler flags that direct to my installation in /usr/include/pcl-1.6. This seems correct, except pcl16_ros is asking for pcl16/* files. And obviously my 1.6 installation doesn't include the version number. So what am I doing wrong here? Or is pcl16_ros just wrong and it should be including pcl/* headers only?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43969/using-different-pcl-version-from-ros-distribution/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the pointless question; I figured it out. The pcl16 package doesn't refer to /usr/include, it runs an svn checkout and builds pcl inside the package itself. So the problem was just that I hadn't build the stack after checking it out.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2012-09-17**:
Further information for anyone else; just install the ubuntu package 'ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable' (http://answers.ros.org/question/39946/upgrading-to-pcl-160-with-ros-fuerte-ubuntu-1204/) Just think of what solving these problems would be like if the answers weren't so well hidden...